# Load Texture from File in HLSL

Tags: file, bitmap, shader, hlsl

I want to blend (in a PostProcessing-Shader) the camera output with a texture. Is there a method to load a texture? something like

```
texture mytexture = "file.bmp"

sampler2D smp = sampler_state {
texture = <mytexture>;
...
}
```

Comment: Which version of Direct3D do you use? 11? Maybe D3DX11CreateTextureFromFile (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476286(v=vs.85).aspx) will work for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A shader is a micro-program, which runs on the gpu. Therefore it isn't capable of something complex like loading textures from disk. The right way to do this, is to load the texture from your program via the DirectX-Api (e.g. `D3DX11CreateTextureFromFile`) and set this resource at the rendercall in the shader to use it there.